# template method "=0" in the parameter list

Tags: c++, c++11

I saw code like the following:

```
using EnableIfIntegral = typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_integral<T>::value || std::is_enum<T>::value, int>::type;

template <typename T, EnableIfIntegral<T> = 0>
constexpr int Seconds(T n) {
  return time_internal::FromInt64(n, std::ratio<1>{});
}

template <std::intmax_t N>
constexpr int FromInt64(int64_t v, std::ratio<1, N>) {
  // Do Something
}
```

I understand what a template function is. Why in the template parameter list, does it have `SomeClass<T> = 0`? I know `T` is the template parameter.

Why is `std::ratio<1, N>` a parameter?

Comment: Can you find the definition of `SomeClass`? If it's a class template, this is not valid in any existing C++ version (but could be in C++20). It could also be a template alias, used here as an SFINAE technique.

Comment: Hi, it's not some class. Sorry.

Comment: A template parameter is one possible place where `std::enable_if` can be applied. When defining a function, it can be applied to a template parameter, a function parameter, or the return type. In this case, a template parameter is used. If `T` is not an integral/enum type, `std::enable_if::type` will not be defined, so `EnableIfIntegral<T>` will not be defined, so `Seconds<T>()` to be ignored. The `= 0` is just so that when `EnabledIfIntegral<T>` is defined, the caller does not have to explicitly pass any value for that template parameter when calling `Seconds()` with a `T` value.

Comment: As for `std::ratio`, it can be useful to represent different units of time. For instance `std::micro` (`std::ratio<1, 1000000>`) for microseconds, `std::milli` (`std::ratio<1, 1000>`) for milliseconds, etc. `FromInt64()` can perform an appropriate calculation depending on the type of `ratio` passed in. In this case, `Seconds()` wants `FromInt64()` to convert `n` to whole seconds (`std::ratio<1, 1>`)

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's practically an answer.

Comment: ```constexpr int FromInt64(int64_t v, std::ratio<1, N>)```  Hi, I not very clear about this one. I can understand v is parameter name and int64_t is parameter type.  What about ```ratio<1,N>``` , what is the variable name here and is ratio<1,N> is the parameter type?

Comment: @echoLee there is no name. The parameter is nameless. `ratio<1,N>` is the parameter type. The body of the function is not using the parameter for anything other than overload purposes, so the parameter doesn't need a name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll answer the first of your two questions.

```
using EnableIfIntegral = typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_integral<T>::value || std::is_enum<T>::value, int>::type;
```

I'm fairly certain that you accidentally left out the previous line, which
should be

```
template<typename T>
```

So the full declaration is

```
template<typename T>
using EnableIfIntegral = typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_integral<T>::value || std::is_enum<T>::value, int>::type;
```

This is pretty big pill to swallow, and I'll come back and discuss the finer details of this declaration in a moment, but what happens here is that if the stars and the moons are alined just right, this becomes:

```
template<typename T>
using EnableIfIntegral = int;
```

In other words, a template type that's just a simple alias for an garden variety `int`. Nothing more than that. Moving onto to the next declaration:

```
template <typename T, EnableIfIntegral<T> = 0>
constexpr int Seconds(T n) {
```

This simply becomes

```
template <typename T, int = 0>
constexpr int Seconds(T n) {
```

In other words, a simple template parameter, an `int` constant that defaults to 0.

That's it, and nothing more. This does absolutely nothing, and that's precisely the intended result here.

The first template parameter, `T` gets deduced from the actual parameter to the `Seconds()` template function. Then the 2nd template parameter passes the `T` template type to the `EnableIfIntegral` template alias declaration, which, hopefully, if all the stars and the moons are properly aligned, does nothing.

Now, when do the stars and the moons properly align? It's when the deduced template type is either some integral type or some `enum` type. Then everything just works.

But if you do something silly, like:

```
std::string what_is_this;

Seconds(what_is_this);
```

A very loose description of what will happen: the first template parameter to `Seconds` gets deduced as `std::string`. So far so good, but we're already doomed because what's inside the `Seconds` template function will not be able to handle a `std::string` value. Normally this will typically result in a typical, indecipherable (to mere mortals) C++ compiler error message.

But things are not going to get this far. What happens first is that the deduced `T` template parameter, which is now `std::string`, gets forwarded to `EnableIfIntegral`, and this template alias will fail to resolve. For all the gory details why, look up what `std::enable_if` does in your favorite C++ book. The exact details of how that happens is not very important, the point is that the template substitution for the `Seconds()` template itself will fail. The compiler will not find a suitable `Seconds` template that will match this function call.

This situation typically produces a much simpler error message from your compiler. Your compiler's error message will be much basic, something along the lines "Hey, what's this Seconds template being called here? I know nothing about it". You will look at the code and realize "Silly me, I'm passing a `std::string` but I need to pass an integral value instead". Oops.

Overall, what this is, is just a common approach to make the pain of using a C++ library less painful, when things go wrong and don't compile. Without this trick, the compiler will whine about the `time_internal::FromInt64` function call (based on the shown code in the question), but there's nothing wrong with that function call. The problem is really with whatever calls `Seconds`, that's where the problem is, and this common approach helps the compiler produce a better error message.

Comment: This is really clear. Thank you.   ```EnableIfIntegral<T> = 0``` you said that  EnableIfIntegral<T> is default to 0 ?  Is  EnableIfIntegral<T>  a non-type template parameter or a template template parameter?   Am I righjt? Thank you.

Comment: `EnableIfIntegral<T>` aliases to `int`, if substitution succeeds, so it becomes effectively an `int`, specifying a non-type `int` template parameter to the template function. `=0` simply gives the default value for the template parameter, so it is not required to be deduced or explicitly given in the invocation of the template function.